# union arrays and keep order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a bunch of arrays and I want to union them, lodash does that:

```
_.union(['a', 'c'], ['a','b', 'c'], ['b', 'z'], ['y']) // ["a", "c", "b", "z", "y"]
```

What I expect is my array to rearrange if required, i.e:

- First occurrence we have `['a', 'c']`
- Second occurrence we have b after a so it should return `['a', 'b', 'c']`
- Third occurrence we have z after b so it should return `['a', 'b', 'z', 'c']`
- Fourth occurrence we have only y so it should be added at the end of the array `['a', 'b', 'z', 'c', 'y']`

I expect:

```
_.union(['a', 'c'], ['a','b', 'c'], ['b', 'z'], ['y']) // ['a', 'b', 'z', 'c', 'y']
```

I have

```
_.union(['a', 'c'], ['a','b', 'c'], ['b', 'z'], ['y']) // ["a", "c", "b", "z", "y"]
```

How could I achieve that?

**Edit**: Tweaked @Andy's fiddle, here's my final working version <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z8nnqp50/4/)</kbd>

Comment: I'd assume you'd have to `sort` after the union

Comment: What do you mean by "rearrange"? I don't grasp the mechanism behind your final expected result.

Comment: I just want to keep the order, if in one array c is before b then the final array should keep this order, `['a', 'b'], ['c', 'b'] => ['a', 'c', 'b']`, because c was before b in the second array.

Comment: Ok, you want to insert values subsequently if I understand well

Comment: @aduch yes that's my goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a long-winded non-lodash version:

```
function union() {
    var arrs = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = arrs.length; i < l; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, jl = arrs[i].length; j < jl; j++) {
            var currEl = arrs[i][j];
            if (out.indexOf(currEl) === -1) {
                if (j - 1 !== -1 && out.indexOf(arrs[i][j - 1]) > -1) {
                    out.splice(out.indexOf(arrs[i][j - 1]) + 1, 0, currEl);
                } else {
                    out.push(currEl);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
};

var result = union(['a', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'z'], ['y']);

console.log(result) // [ "a", "b", "z", "c", "y" ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z8nnqp50/2/)

Comment: It works perfectly until I start to add stuff in front of existing items, see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z8nnqp50/3/